# Content generated from ContentTemplate does not have DataContext of Silverlight ContentControl set

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, datatemplate

In my Silverlight 4 application, I have a `ContentControl` with its `ContentTemplate` property bound to a property in the data context.  That works fine.  However, the content of the template once rendered has its `DataContext` set to `null`.  I would like the content to inherit the same `DataContext` as set for the `ContentControl`.  Is there a way to get this to happen?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found an alternate way to accomplish what was required.  In my case, the template (not the content template) of the `ContentControl` was unimportant, so I made my `DataTemplate` objects into `ControlTemplate` objects instead and bound the `Template` property of the `ContentControl` instead of `ContentTemplate`.  The data context was preserved if I did it this way.

Comment: +1 Question, -1 Answer; I came here wanting to know the same thing, but didn't find an answer. The accepted answer works around the question, but doesn't answer it.

Answer (score 10):

The ContentControl's template has the ContentControl's Content property as a DataContext. So try

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding}" />
```

if this is merely the current DataContext.